# Best practices in the interaction between Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am developing an `application` only to validate the interaction between `activities` through intents.

I created 5 `ImageButton` with an image for each. Each button is a movie and if you click any of them, is directed to a new `activity` with the synopsis of the film. The `activity` with the synopsis, there is an "`up navigation`" that returns the `MainActivity` (home).

The way I developed left very extensive project since created six `activities` (`main activity` and 5 `activities`, one for each film) and 6 `layouts`. Also, my apk is to **1.5mb**.

Could someone help me with suggestions for best practices for I minimize my `code` or how developed is correct and could be developed in a real `application`?

I appreciate!!!

**My MainActivity**

```
package luizugliano.com.br.appfilmes;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

public void onClickBtVideo01(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo01.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo02(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo02.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo03(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo03.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo04(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo04.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickBtVideo05(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo05.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private Context getContext(){
    return this;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**My ActivityVideo01 (other activities have the same code so I only put this as an example)**

```
package luizugliano.com.br.appfilmes;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ActivityVideo01 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_video01);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        //O método finish encerrará essa activity
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**My content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="Sinopse - Filmes" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="22dp"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_marginTop">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton01"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_01"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo01"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton02"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_02"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo02"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton03"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_03"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo03"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton04"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_04"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo04"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton05"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_img_05"
        android:onClick="onClickBtVideo05"/>

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My content_activity_video01.xml (other layout have the same code so I only put this as an example)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_activity_video01"
tools:context="luizugliano.com.br.appfilmes.ActivityVideo01">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Title Synopsis"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Synopsis"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This question is borderline. It's of course a programming question, but it's more about a code review than about a help in some programming error.

Comment: I apologize for that @Frank N. Stein. I'm getting used to using the questions forum. Do you know if the stackoverflow there is another channel for me to publish my question? Thank you so much

Comment: Try [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Try [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

Comment: Thank you so much @AmitTiwari

Comment: Thank you so much @Frank N. Stein

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, that you have two activities, and both these activities will act as container activity for their respective fragments.

In your first activity's fragment have your buttons. In your second activity's fragment, play your movie.

Now when you click on the button, go from first activity's fragment to second activity's fragment. Use interfaces to communicate between your fragments.

This is the way i thought about it, if you have a better way please do share.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead Of taking five different activity just take single activity and replace textview's value dynamically on the click of your button.**

Answer (score 1):

Just marge the two xml file like that in content_main.xml create another relative layout(which is initially `gone` view) with height width match parent under the image button linear layout. When one image button is pressed then just gone the view of linear layout of image buttons and visible the textview relative layout and visible the back button of the up navigation. When user pressed the up navigation just gone the textview relative layout, gone the up navigation and visible the linear layout of image button.

Answer (score 1):

you need not to create multiple activities to show `synopsis` from different films.

you need to create your synopsis activity like a template and pass information about selected film in `intent`.

now you can change the content of your activity depending upon the information you received from intent.

Basically, whenever you are copying the code you need to ask yourself do you really need to copy the code? almost all the time answer is NO and what you actually need to do is, think of ways you can reuse the code you are copying.

Answer (score 1):

Implement onclicklisstener and use switch case to detect which button has been clicked, Use only one activity to display synopsis instead of four and use bundle along with Intent to send which synopsis has to be shown. Here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        //handle multiple view click events
     case R.id.imageButton01:
       //handle click for imgbutton1;
       Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo.class);
       //send which video should be played along with the intent. use bundle in ActivityVideo class to get this value.
       intent.putExtra("Video name", "video1"); 
        startActivity(intent);
     case R.id.imageButton02:
       //handle click for imgbutton2;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo.class);
        intent.putExtra("Video name", "video2"); 
        startActivity(intent);
     case R.id.imageButton03:
       //handle click for imgbutton3;
       Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo.class);
        intent.putExtra("Video name", "video3"); 
        startActivity(intent);
      case R.id.imageButton04:
       //handle click for imgbutton4;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ActivityVideo.class);
         intent.putExtra("Video name", "video4"); 
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Use ActivityVideo class instid of ActivityVideo01, 02 ......

ActivityVideo.java ->

```
public class ActivityVideo01 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_video01);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
 String VideoName = extras.getString("Video Name");
 // VideoName will be having the sent value.
 if(VideoName == "video1"){

  //code for what do you want to do when imagebutton1 is clicked

 }elseif(VideoName == "video2"){

  //code for what do you want to do when imagebutton2 is clicked

 }elseif(VideoName == "video3"){

  //code for what do you want to do when imagebutton3 is clicked

}elseif(VideoName == "video4"){

  //code for what do you want to do when imagebutton4 is clicked

}
 }

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
    //O método finish encerrará essa activity
    finish();
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Hope it helps!